# Advice on Accuracy of World Map (cont)

Tags: geography, map-making

As a continuation of [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167613/advice-on-accuracy-of-world-map).

Thanks to the comments in the previous question, we managed to overhaul the map. It's cleaner and more believable, I think.

However, there were some new questions that were brought up:

1. Should continents fit together like a jigsaw?
2. Where should the magnetic poles be? Will it affect the events on the crust?
3. Do we need an island on every tectonic crack? IS there too many?
4. Where would tornadoes and hurricanes form?
5. Generally are there anything that seems impossible from the examples shown below?

[image]
Ocean currents:
Pink is corals;
Blue is areas for fishing and deposits;
Green is El Nino/Nina hotspots
[image]
Tectonic plates:
Red represent mountain area; 
Blue represent valleys;
Green represent transform lines
[image]
A Hammer projection to have a better sense of the area and proportion of water
[image]

Comment: Usually one question.

Comment: Agreed. Each one of these are great world building questions worthy of its own discussion.  If I were you, I would spend some time researching each question to see if similar ones have been asked before that might answer some of your concerns.  Then revise your map if needed before asking each remaining topic as a separate question.  When you ask a 5 part question like this, it becomes hard to quantify answers as good or bad since a person might say one thing that is very right, but then fall short in the other areas.

Comment: I'm very interested to see where this goes and when you post another question please notify me. I've spent some considerable amount of time myself in trying to figure out how to generate realistic maps starting with plate tectonics, and got pretty overwhelmed with it. I'd be curious to know what resources you find.

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for the spam of questions